# How to clean the salted water in my pool to to water my plants and grass?

Tags: water

We have a 60,000 litre salt water pool that we have not added one drop of chlorine or salt in over 16 months.
What do I need to do to be able to use that water to water my garden and grass?

Comment: Since you mentioned chlorine, does "pool" mean "swimming pool" here, and not "salt-water pond"? Basically, salt and plants don't mix, except for specialised plants that have adapted to grow along the sea shoreline. The salt in the pool water won't disappear unless you do something expensive to get rid of it. Personally I would just forget about the idea.

Comment: If you have salted water, probably you are near sea. Possibly you may have some salt resistant plants, but it is impossible to say from your question. Additionally, by using salt water, you may ruin your soil (it could be difficult/impossible to plant other plants in future). If you have a greenhouse, you may use it (by evaporating), but I doubt you have a climate for greenhouses.

Comment: what part of the world do you live in, do you have a "test area" like a grassy area you can use?

Answer (score 1):

Desalination is *possible*. According to
[Wikipedia ("Desalination")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desalination),

"Currently, approximately 1% of the world's population is dependent on desalinated water to meet daily needs .... The single largest desalination project is Ras Al-Khair in Saudi Arabia, which produced 1,025,000 cubic meters per day in 2014. Kuwait produces a higher proportion of its water than any other country, totaling 100% of its water use."

It looks like people are even working on developing very small-scale desalination processes. E.g. 
[the "Desolenator"](https://www.treehugger.com/solar-technology/small-scale-solar-powered-water-desalination-system.html).

I nearly got sucked down a rabbit hole investigating this, it's so fascinating.... But wow, I concur with Alephzero: big project; not really feasible. (However the Wikipedia article *does have diagrams*....) [j.k.]

Comment: Yeah you would only need direct access to like 3MW power plant, no biggie! XD